# Using Retrofit 2 and Aws Signed Url to Upload File

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, retrofit

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon's S3 using a pre-signed URL. I get the URL from a server which generates the URL. I already successfully used this URL and postman to upload a file to s3.

Now I want to do the same with Retrofit in android. To do that, I have written the following code:

```
@PUT
    Call<Void> updateImage(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody image);
```

```
String CONTENT = "application/zip";

                        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(CONTENT), gpxfile);

                        
                        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl("http://www.dummy.com/")
                                .build();

                        APIService imageInterface = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
                       
                        Call<Void> call = imageInterface.updateImage(url, requestFile);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                                Log.d(response.message(), response.raw().toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });
```

But the response i get is: Forbidden: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://...

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong or provide me an tutorial to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is `gpxfile`? Also, have you tried adding the OkHttp logging interceptor, or Flipper's OkHttp interceptor, so you can see exactly what you are sending?

Comment: gpxfile is a zip file.

Comment: No i have not added a logging interceptor. might have to try that

Comment: "gpxfile is a zip file" -- OK, but that does not give us much to go on. Where is this ZIP file, with respect to storage on the device? How did you get its path?